# Read pdf file from downloads directory with python using pdfrw library

Tags: python-3.x, pdfrw

I want to manipulate pdf file using PDFRW library, so when I try to get the source of the pdf file I can't get the file and read it so please help.

```
  from pdfrw import pdfreader
  import os
  import pathlib

  pdf_file = pdfreader('C:\\Users/4488\\Downloads\\Life-of-Muhammad.pdf')


  print(pdf_file.Keys())


        this is the error that I am getting

        Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "c:\Users\4488\desktop\Xhamar-Project\xhamar.py", line 8, in 
        <module>
        get_file = pdfreader(pdf_file)
        TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: Please make your question clearer, what errors do you get? What is the expected result? What have you tried already?

Comment: Also, whilst I don't believe it actually makes a difference, it is best to be consistent with whether you use `/` or `\ ` in your filepaths. For backwards compatibility reasons on windows, I would recommend `\ ` (`\\ `).

Answer (score 1):

I know... I'm a bit late, but in case you didn't figured it out:

Try to use `pdfrw.PdfReader()` instead of `pdfrw.pdfreader()`

Have a nice day